# git log --follow, show all commits including merges

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to `git log --follow file.ext` but showing all commits, including merges.

Tried `no-max-parents`, but not helping.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> The `-m` will do the trick for you, `log -m` is for get into the merges.

`git log -m --oneline --full-history --follow file.ext`

This should follow the file  in the Merges [`-m`].

And i assume you was aiming to use `--min-parents=2` instead of `no-max-parents`. The `--min-parents=2` is the same as `--merged` since it will return the commit with more then one parent.

You can always add some extra flags to display the results in a more friendly way:
`git log -m --name-only --oneline --follow file.ext`. It will display the results with the SHA-1 of the commits as well with the message

Comment: For me, `-m` adds a lot more merges than would be "natural". For example, `git log file.ext` shows 10 normal commits and 2 merge commits for me, `git log --follow -m file.ext` lists 10 normal commits and 30 (!!) merge commits.

Comment: @BorekBernard I find the documentation a bit unclear, but it sounds like the option `--simplify-merges` may be meant to help this: "Additional option to --full-history to remove some needless merges from the resulting history, as there are no selected commits contributing to this merge."