# Git log for a directory including merges

Tags: git

I'm writing a scripts that takes a path as a parameter and outputs Git commits for that path, similarly to what GitHub does when you click the *History* button in some folder (here's [an example](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/commits/master/docs)). In essence, I wanted to write the script like this:

```
git log -10 --oneline -- "$directory"
```

However, I have a lot of trouble making it work reliably for both the root folder and subdirectories, and for various configurations of the `follow` behavior. After the experiments below, I also think that I'm misunderstanding how `git log` works with various flags in the first place so it would be great if someone could help me understand that.

> Note: in our case, we need to pass multiple directories sometimes, which is why I'm trying to make pathspec work, as opposed to something like `cd subdirectory && git log`.

The examples are from the [`versionpress/versionpress`](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress) repository (in the [2071052a](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/tree/2071052ad33a782e96ca206ccca6891e52bc614f) state) and I have tested it in both Git for Windows 2.17.1.windows.2 and on Linux with Git 2.14.1.

First, a basic log for the `docs` folder:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline -- docs
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
8244d42a Added link to announcement blog post
da97c7c3 Merge branch 'master' into 1263-pre-4.0beta-polish
5c99bc30 Merge pull request #1270 from versionpress/4.0-beta-release-notes
f22b0e27 4.0-beta release notes updated, are now close to final
f0de171f Specific WordPress version used in dev-env Dockerfile, Dev-Setup slightly updated
bcd6d4e8 package-lock JSONs updated for npm 5.1 (there were some issues reported with 5.0)
1438bc43 Documented running tests by picking a test suite from phpunit.xml, the "other tests" documented in more detail
5af500d4 Better instructions on running specific tests from CLI, tests' docker-compose.yml cleaned up, various other testing "readme" updates
```

Good, this is [same as on GitHub](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/commits/2071052ad33a782e96ca206ccca6891e52bc614f/docs).

Now, the same for the root directory:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline -- .
94084136 Typo in the activation message
8a15a8b1 Added error when re-activating VP with WP CLI
6ad07b7d package-lock.json updated
e7e356f8 Updated WP and WP-CLI versions in ext-libs
777e2d05 Disable event propagation after click on the commit table checkbox
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
32d6dbe2 Installed WordPress version bumpted to 4.9
459c2e6d package-lock.json updated for npm 5.5
77ad593c Link to Gitter and support repo in ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
```

Not good, merge commits are missing. I can remove the path spec to get them:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline
2071052a (HEAD -> master, temp/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #1318 from aidik/master
94084136 Typo in the activation message
129bf972 Merge pull request #1314 from x1024/master
8a15a8b1 Added error when re-activating VP with WP CLI
288e305d Merge pull request #1310 from versionpress/1307-wp-update-fixes
6ad07b7d package-lock.json updated
e7e356f8 Updated WP and WP-CLI versions in ext-libs
f8d22592 Merge pull request #1309 from versionpress/1308-fix-commits-table-checkboxes
777e2d05 Disable event propagation after click on the commit table checkbox
06208405 Merge pull request #1307 from versionpress/wp-4.9-for-test-sites
```

But this is impractical for my script, plus I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong because I believe that the output of `git log` and `git log -- .` should be the same, shouldn't it?

From my experiments, it seems that the `--full-history` flag adds the merge commits when run on the `.` directory:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --full-history -- .
2071052a (HEAD -> master, temp/master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #1318 from aidik/master
94084136 Typo in the activation message
129bf972 Merge pull request #1314 from x1024/master
8a15a8b1 Added error when re-activating VP with WP CLI
288e305d Merge pull request #1310 from versionpress/1307-wp-update-fixes
6ad07b7d package-lock.json updated
e7e356f8 Updated WP and WP-CLI versions in ext-libs
f8d22592 Merge pull request #1309 from versionpress/1308-fix-commits-table-checkboxes
777e2d05 Disable event propagation after click on the commit table checkbox
06208405 Merge pull request #1307 from versionpress/wp-4.9-for-test-sites
```

However, it "breaks" the docs subdirectory (note the first merge commit which shouldn't be there):

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --full-history -- docs
06208405 Merge pull request #1307 from versionpress/wp-4.9-for-test-sites
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
8244d42a Added link to announcement blog post
9671af87 (tag: 4.0-beta) Merge pull request #1283 from versionpress/1263-pre-4.0beta-polish
da97c7c3 Merge branch 'master' into 1263-pre-4.0beta-polish
5c99bc30 Merge pull request #1270 from versionpress/4.0-beta-release-notes
f22b0e27 4.0-beta release notes updated, are now close to final
f0de171f Specific WordPress version used in dev-env Dockerfile, Dev-Setup slightly updated
bcd6d4e8 package-lock JSONs updated for npm 5.1 (there were some issues reported with 5.0)
```

This can be "fixed" by adding `--simplify-merges`:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --full-history --simplify-merges -- docs
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
8244d42a Added link to announcement blog post
da97c7c3 Merge branch 'master' into 1263-pre-4.0beta-polish
5c99bc30 Merge pull request #1270 from versionpress/4.0-beta-release-notes
f22b0e27 4.0-beta release notes updated, are now close to final
b8a138ce Fixed path of plugin definition discovery
48333d82 4.0-beta release notes written (some TODOs still remaining)
2c61613f 4.0-alpha1 Markdown file renamed to such (used to be just 4.0) and updated to contain the same info as the GitHub release page
f0de171f Specific WordPress version used in dev-env Dockerfile, Dev-Setup slightly updated
```

But that also causes trouble for the `.` directory:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --full-history --simplify-merges -- .
94084136 Typo in the activation message
8a15a8b1 Added error when re-activating VP with WP CLI
6ad07b7d package-lock.json updated
e7e356f8 Updated WP and WP-CLI versions in ext-libs
777e2d05 Disable event propagation after click on the commit table checkbox
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
32d6dbe2 Installed WordPress version bumpted to 4.9
459c2e6d package-lock.json updated for npm 5.5
77ad593c Link to Gitter and support repo in ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
```

I tried the `-m` flag as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30444549/21728) but with no differences.

Now, is a user has `log.follow` set to `true` in their config, there is also some behavior that I don't fully understand.

```
$ git config --global log.follow true
(empty output)

$ git log -10 --oneline --merges -- .
(empty output)
```

No merge commits at all, even when asked for it. I need to add `--no-follow` (should probably be documented in Git docs):

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --merges --no-follow -- .
da97c7c3 Merge branch 'master' into 1263-pre-4.0beta-polish
5c99bc30 Merge pull request #1270 from versionpress/4.0-beta-release-notes
aba96d3f Merge pull request #1277 from versionpress/1274-using-filter-on-init
82a3fd4e Merge pull request #1269 from versionpress/ext-libs-install-locked
ccb74422 Merge pull request #1251 from versionpress/1120-edit-update-action
a94dc0d3 Merge pull request #1246 from versionpress/1176-plugin-definition-discovery
ae530356 Merge pull request #1260 from versionpress/1154-temp-in-zip
ffd7647e Merge pull request #1170 from versionpress/1168-getmenureference-broken
f4a00328 Merge branch 'master' into 1120-edit-update-action
7b29e7ed Merge branch 'master' into 1041-dockerized-dev-setup
```

So my hope would be that adding `--no-follow` and removing `--merges` would produce the expected output, however, it still misses merge commits in that case:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --no-follow -- .
94084136 Typo in the activation message
8a15a8b1 Added error when re-activating VP with WP CLI
6ad07b7d package-lock.json updated
e7e356f8 Updated WP and WP-CLI versions in ext-libs
777e2d05 Disable event propagation after click on the commit table checkbox
81554a46 Small updates of Dev-Setup.md
32d6dbe2 Installed WordPress version bumpted to 4.9
459c2e6d package-lock.json updated for npm 5.5
77ad593c Link to Gitter and support repo in ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
84d3229e Updated intro message to mention beta instead of alpha
```

This is consistent with the behavior above but I still don't understand it: I would assume that `git log` is essentially a combined output of `git log --no-merges` and `git log --merges` but it's not the case when a path is specified.

Any explanation of this would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**: Maybe the issue is not with merge commits vs. plain commits. I've tried in another repo and compare the outputs when the path is not specified vs. when it's `.`:

```
$ git log -10 --oneline --no-follow
350df16f6 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #1977 from versionpress/1975-do-not-upgrade-deleted-sites
21db78245 Merge branch 'master' into 1975-do-not-upgrade-deleted-sites
0a4eda432 Upgrading only sites that are not deleted
43cd96ac9 Merge pull request #1971 from versionpress/fix-ui-creation-of-sites
a952ae1c5 Merge pull request #1966 from versionpress/1949-reduce-db-migrate-boilerplate
018e4d3b7 Merge pull request #1969 from versionpress/1964-platform-api-easy-local-run
4515bc242 Fix add a new site button
6e4ecd652 Merge branch 'master' into prod
4229e326a Fixed Makefile of default-backend
fc99e0f19 [hotfix] Disabled removing TLS hosts

$ git log -10 --oneline --no-follow -- .
21db78245 Merge branch 'master' into 1975-do-not-upgrade-deleted-sites
0a4eda432 Upgrading only sites that are not deleted
43cd96ac9 Merge pull request #1971 from versionpress/fix-ui-creation-of-sites
a952ae1c5 Merge pull request #1966 from versionpress/1949-reduce-db-migrate-boilerplate
018e4d3b7 Merge pull request #1969 from versionpress/1964-platform-api-easy-local-run
4515bc242 Fix add a new site button
4229e326a Fixed Makefile of default-backend
fc99e0f19 [hotfix] Disabled removing TLS hosts
d1bcdae2d Replace 'db-migrate-boilerplate' with a custom implementation
c60032144 Kubernetes.ts returned to its original, non-async structure before 36308d3 with the token loading logic moved to `server.ts` (it didn't really belong to Kubernetes.ts).
```

It's just a different set of commits and I don't see a clear pattern in including / excluding commits here...

---

Some possibly relevant things from [git-log docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

- There is a long section on [History simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification), maybe there are some answers in there (didn't study it fully yet).
- About `log.follow` configuration (emphasis mine): *If true, git log will act as if the --follow option was used when a single  is given. This has the same limitations as --follow, i.e. it cannot be used to follow multiple files and **does not work well on non-linear history**.*

---

Adding some discussion from `#git` IRC:

[16:44] <+borekb> hi, should `git log` and `git log -- .` produce the same results? it seems that the latter is missing some merge commits, sometimes, and I don't quite understand why
[16:45]  borekb: it might depend on what directory you are in?
[16:45] <+borekb> I'm in a root of a project
[16:45] <+borekb> I've posted some examples here: [Git log for a directory including merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719083)
[16:46] <+borekb> and honestly don't understand what is going on :) I feel like I must be missing something obvious as `git log` is such a basic command that I've used like a million times, though without a path spec
[16:48]  borekb: that might be "history simplification". It's described on man git log.
[16:48] <@gitinfo> borekb: the git-log manpage is available at https://gitirc.eu/git-log.html
[16:49]  borekb: oh, based on SO looks like you were already on track.
[16:50] <+borekb> rafasc: I also suspect it's that (direct link: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification), but would it be fair to assume that by default, the `git log` and `git log -- .` should "simplify" to the same output?
[16:50] <+borekb> my head exploded a little bit when I tried to read that section :)
[16:51]  I think the answer i no. It's not safe to assume that. --  is a form of history simplification. So you're telling git you want simplification.
[16:54] <+borekb> good point
[16:56] <+borekb> from my experiments, it looks like `-- path` is behaving differently when it's some subfolder (`git log -- docs`) vs. when it's just the current directory (`git log -- .`).
[16:56] <+borekb> subfolder works as expected, `.` produces results I do not quite understand
[16:57]  borekb: it has to do with that section on the man page that talks what is TREESAME and what isn't.
[16:57]  borekb: try dummy_folder/.. :P
[16:59] <+borekb> up_here: clever hack but doesn't work :)
[17:01]  borekb: unrelated, but when using online to inspect commits, you might want to use --show-linear-break, in order to understand the relation between commits. (note that --graph --online might also be misleading, graph needs at least two lines to draw the edges, --pretty=short in that case is useful)
[17:02] <+borekb> rafasc: oh that's nice
[17:03] <+borekb> rafac: how would you estimate chance of there being a combination of flags that would lead to `git log -- .` producing exactly the same output as `git log`? I'm asking before I dive into the TREESAME discussion which *will* be pain for me :)
[17:05]  borekb: from memory, I would say --full-history... But you had problems with that right?
[17:06] <+borekb> rafasc: yep, --full-history makes more commits appear in `git log -- subdirectory`

Comment: Is the expected behavior of --no-follow the opposite of --follow? Because the latter according to the documentation "works only for a single file" and I see that you are working with directories.

Comment: @ChristosBatzilis I'm not sure. The way I understand the documentation is that the `follow` flag or config should only influence logs for a single file, but it's clearly having some effect if the path is a directory as well.

Comment: I've posted an important update from another repo: it might not be merge commits vs. plain commits after all. See the bottom part of the post.

Comment: I have a theory. I think the delta here are indeed the merge commits. The ones that still appear with '-- .' are probably not real merge commits but autogenerated 'merge commits' created with --squash and --ff. Could it be?

Comment: In the examples above, it's standard merge commits, created by merging pull requests via GitHub most of the time.

Comment: But the question is, are they real merge commits? So, do you see them when you run 'git log --oneline --merges' ?. My suspicion is that the are actually commits created by Github by squashing all commits of a given branch and putting the new one linearly on top of master.

Comment: Yes, they are standard commits with two parents. One example of them is here: https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/commit/da97c7c3cb0f5e9a8031eec041d41c05376555bc#diff-e3e2a9bfd88566b05001b02a3f51d286

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are indeed being bitten by History Simplification.  Note that simplification is enabled by default when using any path names with `git log`.  It is *not* enabled by default if you do not supply path names.  Adding particular options, like `--full-history` or `--simplify-*`

(You may also get bitten by the implied `--follow` from having `log.follow` set to `true`, but it's harder to see where that would occur for this particular case.)

The simplification works by doing very limited `git diff`s.  Remember that as `git log` is walking through the commit graph, it is working on one commit *C* at a time.  Each commit *C* has some set of parent commits.  For an ordinary (non-merge) commit, there is just one parent, so for each file in *C* that is to be examined—based on the path names you gave—either that file in *C* is 100% identical to that file in its parent *P*, or it's different, and that's easy for Git to tell because a path that is 100% identical in both commits has the same *blob hash* in the commit's attached tree.

That's what the TREESAME expression in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) means: we take commit *C*'s tree, remove all the paths that *aren't* being examined, leaving (in memory—none of this affects anything stored in the repository!) a skeleton tree attached to *C* that has the files that *are* being examined.  Then we take the (single) parent *P* and do the same thing.  The result is either matching—*C* and its parent *P* are TREESAME—or non-matching.

The commit is "interesting" and will be displayed if it's interesting.  Even if it's not interesting, Git will still put the parent *P* into the graph-walk priority queue to examine later, because this is just an ordinary commit and Git *must* walk through it to construct a history.  (There's some weirdness here with "parent rewriting" that I'm going to skip over, though it matters for `--graph`.)

At *merges*, however, things are different.  Commit *C* still has its one tree as usual, but it has multiple parent commits *P<sub>i</sub>*.  Git will do the same "strip down the tree" operation for *each* parent.  When you're not using `--full-history`, Git will then compare the stripped-down trees of *C* vs each *P<sub>i</sub>*.  The merge itself is included if it's not TREESAME to *any* parent, but if it *is* TREESAME to at least one parent *P<sub>i</sub>*, the merge tends to get excluded (depending on other options) *and* Git puts *only* that parent into the priority queue for walking through the graph.  If *C* is TREESAME to multiple P<sub>i</sub> *P<sub>j</sub>* *P<sub>k</sub>* ..., Git picks one of these parents randomly and discards the rest, by default.

Adding `--full-history` disables the discarding of all but one *P<sub>i</sub>*.  So now Git will walk all the parents of the merge.  This doesn't affect whether the merge itself is displayed, it just makes sure that Git walks both "sides" of the merge, or all arms if it's a multi-way octopus merge.

**The logic here is that if the file(s) you're looking at are the same in commit *C* and commit *P<sub>i</sub>*, why then, you don't *care* that they're *different* in some other parent *P<sub>o</sub>*, because the file has its current form due to parent *P<sub>i</sub>* rather than parent *P<sub>o</sub>*.**  This logic is correct if you think that the file(s) you are looking at are *right*, but falls apart if you think they are *wrong* and you are looking for the merge that lost the changes you wanted.

#### A separate note on `--follow`

(Since your path name is `.`, and Git generally does not do directories at all—using a directory name really means *all files anywhere under the directory, recursively*—this shouldn't matter here.  If you use a *file* name, though, it might matter.  Remember that `--follow` is only obeyed if you're looking at *exactly one file*.)

The way that `--follow` works, which is the reason it only works for one path name (and shouldn't be a problem with `.` as the path), is that when Git is doing this *choose whether a commit that we walk, as we walk through the commit graph, is interesting and should therefore be displayed* testing, it's doing these `git diff`s on each commit vs its parent(s).

Unlike the TREESAME diff, the `--follow` test is a full diff—it's more expensive than the quick 100%-the-same, at least for the more interesting problem cases—but it's limited to one file, which keeps it from being *too* costly.  It also applies only to single-parent commits, though this comes after `--first-parent` (if you used that) strips away the other parents or after `-m` (if you used that) splits a merge into multiple virtual commits that share the same tree, or after history simplification has picked just one parent to follow.<sup>1</sup>  In any case, if the parent does not have a file with the (single) path name that you're logging, Git does a full diff of the parent and the child to see if it can find some *renamed* file in the parent.  If it *can* find such a renamed file, first it shows the child—because the file changed: it was at the very least renamed after all—and then Git *changes the path name it is looking for* as it traverses to the child's parent.

That is, Git started out looking for `dir/sub/file.ext`, hit a commit *C* where the *parent* of *C* didn't *have* a `dir/sub/file.ext`, did a full-blown diff, and found a *sufficiently similar* file named `path/to/old.name`.  So Git shows you commit *C*, saying `R<percent> path/to/old.name -> dir/sub/file.ext`, and then moves on to *P*—but now instead of looking for changes to the path `dir/sub/file.ext`, it's looking for changes to the path `path/to/old.name`.

This particular trick *can't* work well across all merges: the file could be renamed in just one of the various arms of the merge, or it could be renamed in multiple arms, depending on who did the renaming and when.  Git can only look for *one* path name—it doesn't keep looking for both names.  Of course, supplying a path name turns on history simplification, so in general there aren't any merges to worry about after all.  The merge case happens only if you use a flag like `--full-history` or `--simplify-merges`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that if History Simplification has picked one parent from a merge, it has picked a *P* that is TREESAME to *C* after stripping out all files except the one we care about—so by definition, the one file we're `--follow`ing in *C* matches the same-named file in parent *P*.  This means commit *C* will turn out to be uninteresting after all.

Comment: Thanks, that is great insight into how `git log` works. So is there a combination of flags that would make `git log -- .` produce exactly the same result as `git log` when run from the repo root?

Comment: I don't think there is anything that is 100% the same: `--full-history` comes closest as it adds all parents of a merge to the priority queue, but it still omits from the *display* any commits that make no change ("empty" commits). What's not at all clear is why you saw an extra merge commit this way, vs no options at all. BTW when experimenting, if you can, draw a full graph of all reachable commits (`git log --graph` will draw one for you) so you can think about how Git is simplifying at merges.

Comment: What if 'git log -- .' is the actual, "logical" log and I'm just too used to seeing plain old 'git log' and assume that is the expected output? In other words, if you view history of the root folder on GitHub and then do the same for some subfolder, are you really seeing a comparable thing? That thought is too radical for me though, I need to let it sink in.

Comment: Well, running `git log` with *no* switches—you can still give it some number of starting-point commits—simply walks the graph and shows each commit it encounters, in the order they come off the priority queue. But `git log -- .` walks the graph doing History Simplification, which omits some commits entirely *from* the walk, and also shows only some of the commits selected *during* the walk. So they are different, at least potentially, depending on which commits are omitted from the walk and which ones are selected for showing.