# Git show doesn't show all commits when using the file filter

Tags: git

When using the option `-- *.ps1` behind the command `git show 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912..HEAD --name-only -m --pretty=oneline` I don't get all the commits which I expect.

When I enter the following command (without the filter)

```
git show 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912..HEAD --name-only -m --pretty=oneline
```

Result:

```
b11dc7a851805de2b938eb7728775cdf3b289980 (from bef83b7bf4631b99352e910e737e70dabf6e9f7e) (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merged PR 336: mergeo ti master**
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
applicationinsights/azuredeploy.json
asc/azuredeploy.json
3e95c56d8ebdafebc505a77cfa82823fe8dac625 (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop) Merged PR 335: asc to 3.1.1.0
asc/azuredeploy.json
7e3cee91802e825fab67bc0543940de89f801399 Merged PR 334: ain to 1.4.1.0
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
applicationinsights/azuredeploy.json
bef83b7bf4631b99352e910e737e70dabf6e9f7e (from c7f7d091641fd087db7d495ecd6ffc3d3276d195) Merged PR 333: to master aco
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
b15d05d5e4cbe3c3471373299c0feb42a5bd5724 (from 7d1a89144110b6614aa2d8e9593915e1a72698a2) Merged PR 332: vv
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
ce28d9802df96d1e8aab6cf843a394e363afcee9 vv
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
c7f7d091641fd087db7d495ecd6ffc3d3276d195 (from 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912) Merged PR 331: to master
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
7d1a89144110b6614aa2d8e9593915e1a72698a2 (from 4572605c065a05cda35b738e9a34ef86b1bbffca) Merged PR 330: upd
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
a48fe4a3e63c8de14c82b4c067f627ddfc20a809 upd
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
```

when using with a filter
`git show 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912..HEAD --name-only -m --pretty=oneline -- *.ps1`

Result:

```
7e3cee91802e825fab67bc0543940de89f801399 Merged PR 334: ain to 1.4.1.0
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
ce28d9802df96d1e8aab6cf843a394e363afcee9 vv
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
a48fe4a3e63c8de14c82b4c067f627ddfc20a809 upd
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
```

Every where **(from [hashid] ....)** is mentioned in the first list, doesn't show up in the list when using the filter.

For example, I also expected the following line to appear:

```
bef83b7bf4631b99352e910e737e70dabf6e9f7e (from c7f7d091641fd087db7d495ecd6ffc3d3276d195) Merged PR 333: to master aco
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
apiconnection/azuredeploy.json
```

I expect there is some lack in mine git knowledge, but i cannot figured it out after a lot of searching.

Comment: [`-m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_combined_diff_format) filters for only first parents. Try it out without the flag.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same result, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724301/6003916). This made me try to add `--follow` to mine command, this gives me the result I want. so the complete command become:

```
git show 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912..HEAD --name-only -m --follow --pretty=oneline -- *.ps1
```

Result:

```
b11dc7a851805de2b938eb7728775cdf3b289980 (from bef83b7bf4631b99352e910e737e70dabf6e9f7e) (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merged PR 336: mergeo ti master
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
7e3cee91802e825fab67bc0543940de89f801399 Merged PR 334: ain to 1.4.1.0
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
bef83b7bf4631b99352e910e737e70dabf6e9f7e (from c7f7d091641fd087db7d495ecd6ffc3d3276d195) Merged PR 333: to master aco
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
b15d05d5e4cbe3c3471373299c0feb42a5bd5724 (from 7d1a89144110b6614aa2d8e9593915e1a72698a2) Merged PR 332: vv
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
ce28d9802df96d1e8aab6cf843a394e363afcee9 vv
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
c7f7d091641fd087db7d495ecd6ffc3d3276d195 (from 8b8aab476011f97a2885607fc6e872ec72e5a912) Merged PR 331: to master
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
7d1a89144110b6614aa2d8e9593915e1a72698a2 (from 4572605c065a05cda35b738e9a34ef86b1bbffca) Merged PR 330: upd
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
a48fe4a3e63c8de14c82b4c067f627ddfc20a809 upd
_cicd/GetRevisions.ps1
```