# Git latest commit in topo-order including merge commits, which made any change in a directory

Tags: git, git-merge, git-log

In a Git repository, on the `main` (or `master`) branch, I would like to identify the "latest" commit in the topological order, including merge commits, which made any change in a specified directory.

#### More context:

I have a kind of mono-repo managed on GitHub. Imagine it's like below:

```
/
|-- file1
|-- file2
|-- subproject1/
|   |-- file1-1
|   `-- file1-2
|-- subproject2/
|   `-- file2-1
`-- subproject3/
    `-- file3-1
```

- Assume it's on GitHub
- Assume any force push is prohibited on the `main` branch (by restricting on GitHub)
- Assume the `main` branch can be updated with the latest commit of :

  - A plain (non-merge) commit by :

    - "Rebase and merge" (whose last commit is a plain commit) from a pull request
    - "Squash and merge" from a pull request
    - A direct fast-forward push (whose last commit is a plain commit) on `main`
  - A merge commit by :

    - "Merge pull request" from a pull request
    - "Rebase and merge" (whose last commit is a merge commit) from a pull request
    - A direct fast-forward push (whose last commit is a merge commit) on `main`
- Under those assumptions, I'd like to identify :

  - the "latest" commit (either a plain or merge commit above) that made any change in a specific directory, ex, `subproject1/`,
  - in the topological order (not author-date nor commit-date)
  - from `HEAD` of the current `main` branch

I looked into these questions and answers below, but not very sure...

- [git log --follow, show all commits including merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443906/git-log-follow-show-all-commits-including-merges)
- [Git log for a directory including merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719083/git-log-for-a-directory-including-merges)

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Use `git log` or `git rev-list` with `--topo-order` and the path name of the directory in question. Add `--full-history` to avoid history pruning if you want to inspect commits that *didn't* contribute to the *current* state (where "current" is defined as whatever the tree looks like in your start point for your topo-order walk).

Comment: No, it does not include merge commits. That's the point of my question.

Comment: The fact that the output does not list the merge commits themselves is the key to your question. Add `-m` to make log and rev-list inspect the diffs from each merge to each parent, which will make the merge commits participate in the file-diff "do/don't print this commit" selection test. (I missed this point in my initial scan of your question.)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, `-m` added some merge commits, but they were too many, then I made this question. Okay, I'll have to inspect every merge commit to check whether it's to be included or not...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a plain : `git log -1 -- path/to/directory`

Comment: No, it does not include merge commits. That's the point of my question